# How to dynamically change a page title through some administration parameter

Tags: joomla

I'm a newbie in CMSs, namely Joomla.
I have a website in Joomla and I have made a custom template for my layout.

When a specific menu item is loaded I want, for example, to change the page header title, or apply a css file. Desirably the page title or css file should be set in Joomla administration page.

The goal is for some pages/menu items apply different titles or css files without create a new custom template.
I've heard in custom parameters but I'm not sure if that do the job.
Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the menu item into the System Parameters slider. There you can set different titles and CSS classes for the whole page. (You might have to change your template to actually use that feature the way you want. Just guessing that it might not be doing exactly what you want out of the box.)